# Conversion to list of list from a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, return, executable

I am trying to execute a C file from a python code by running the C executable. Below is my code:

```
import subprocess
import sys

dataset = sys.argv[1]
def func():
    subprocess.run(['/home/dev/exec_file', dataset, 'outfile'])
    f_result = []
    f = open('outfile', "r")
    content = f. read()
    f_result.append(content)
    print(f_result)
    #print(content.rstrip('\n'))
    return f_result
```

Here if I simply write `print(content.rstrip('\n'))` then it gives output like:

```
*,*,1,*,0
*,*,2,2,1
*,*,*,3,1
*,*,*,4,2
*,*,3,*,2
```

Now I want to return a list of list. I mean it will look like:

```
[['*', '*', '1', '*', '0'], ['*', '*', '2', '2', '1'], ['*', '*', '*', '3', '1'], ['*', '*', '*', '4', '2'], ['*', '*', '3', '*', '2']]
```

In my above approach `print(f_result)` is giving output like: `['*,*,1,*,0\n*,*,2,2,1\n*,*,*,3,1\n*,*,*,4,2\n*,*,3,*,2\n']`

How can I do it and return a list of list from this? Please help.

Comment: Look into the `split` function to split a string on a newline character, and then on a comma character per list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and `str.split`:

```
content = '*,*,1,*,0\n*,*,2,2,1\n*,*,*,3,1\n*,*,*,4,2\n*,*,3,*,2\n'

[l.split(',') for l in content.rstrip('\n').split('\n')]
```

output:

```
[['*', '*', '1', '*', '0'],
 ['*', '*', '2', '2', '1'],
 ['*', '*', '*', '3', '1'],
 ['*', '*', '*', '4', '2'],
 ['*', '*', '3', '*', '2']]
```

Comment: I am updating my code like : `f = open('outfile', "r")
 content = f. read()
 [l.split(',') for l in content.rstrip('\n').split('\n')]
 print(content)`

Will it work fine?

Comment: I was just confirming that. Yes it is working absolutely fine. Thanks a lot. :)